# Load another application with a different IP default gateway

Tags: windows, gateway

this is the situation:
a company with two internet connections with two routers in the same subnet.
There are two gateways: 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.254.
One connection is more reliable, the other is faster.

What they want is to start some applications (3rd party) giving them the reliable gateway (.254), while all other applications use the fast one (.1)

What I'm searching for is a possibility to execute another process making him believe that the gateway is .254, while all other applications run on the .1

does anyone know of a way how to do that? If possible in .net?

Comment: If you are using Windows XP (Any should do the trick), you can use an undocumented API called `SetAdapterIpAddress`, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369597/segmentation-fault-when-changing-default-gateway) is an example on how to use it.

Comment: hi if you find answer to your question, please share with us